# Will an open source .NET framework allow built-in Windows program compatibility?

Tags: windows, wine

As probably at least a few people know, Microsoft made the .NET application framework open source.

Does this mean that it will be possible to run more Windows programs on Linux, and somehow speed up wine by directly integrating APIs? Or is it more of just a development system that won't be possible to natively integrate to run as smoothly as programs written to use bash?

I've used wine and found that, even on distros where it is natively installed it ends up running slowly even for the most basic programs, and with virtual disks and such it ends up being a pain to use. Will it be possible to integrate the APIs on a core/kernel level, maybe change a couple things so that slashes are represented differently, and throw in a reported Windows version and let them run as they would natively? If anyone thinks this is going to be possible only once pigs fly on their own please tell me that it won't ever work, but I'd like to know specifically why it would or would not work, not just a one word answer.

Comment: Although it makes sense that this was closed as *too broad*--on the face of it, it seems like it's asking several things--I think it's really [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/185080) where the real issue at hand is narrow enough. See [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/553892/22949), which succinctly addresses everything that's really being asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wine got to do with it? Let's ignore that for a moment.

Microsoft are open sourcing the core parts of .NET as well as making ASP.NET more open source than it already was. On their own, these two parts would allow you to make command line applications and ASP.NET websites. If you have existing applications like this, it should eventually be possible to create Linux targets (if that's even required) and run them natively on Ubuntu.

That said, there are a whole fleet of .NET components required to make something like a GUI application. On Windows, developers use things like the Windows Presentation Foundation to draw things on the screen. In Mono, we can use things like GTK# and Qt#. If you want a cross-platform application, you need a cross-platform toolkit.

That's a very long winded way of saying not much is going to change initially. Developers could use Mono before if they wanted cross-platform apps and they still can. In the future it'll perhaps be easier to pull in Mono's toolkits into a VS.NET project, or MS will replace WPF with a cross-platform toolkit.

Back to Wine. A .NET application running in Wine will still need something to provide it with presentation libraries and (if native Windows libraries) they're going to need to still go *through* Wine so the right environment is provided for them. Wine is still the link between application and hardware (well virtual hardware through Linux) that .NET sits on top of. I can't see that arrangement changing any time soon.